# Soap Client __soapCall - silent error

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to connect to Royal Mail Shipping API and I can't figure it out why on $soapClient->__soapCall($method, $params) the script stops executing. No errors shows on the screen or in logs.

WSDL is pulled from local file and the __getFunctions() returns methods available so I'm assuming this is fine.

Creating soapClient object:

```
    $soapClientOptions = array(
        'cache_wsdl' => 'WSDL_CACHE_NONE',
        'local_cert' => NULL,
        //'ssl_method' => 'SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv3',
        'location' => $this->apiLocation,
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create($this->getAuthenticationHeaders()),
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
        'trace' => true,
        'exceptions' => true
    );

    try {
        $soapClient = new SoapClient($this->getStaticEndPoint(), $soapClientOptions);
    } catch(\SoapFault $fault){
        $error      =   "SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}\n" ."faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})"; 
        echo $error;
    }catch(\Exception $exception){
        echo "<BR>".$exception;
    }
    $headerObject = new SoapVar($this->getWsseSecurityHeaders(), XSD_ANYXML);
    $header = new SoapHeader($this->moduleRoot.'/reference/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd', 'Security', $headerObject);
    $soapClient->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

Below is the code for __soapCall

```
    while (true) {
        try {
            $response = $soapClient->__soapCall('createShipment', array());
        } catch (\SoapFault $fault) {
            trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getCode().': '.$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

SoapClient object:

```
object(SoapClient)#1641 (6) {
  ["location"]=>
  string(37) "https://api.royalmail.net/shipping/v2"
  ["trace"]=>
  int(1)
  ["_stream_context"]=>
  resource(4652) of type (stream-context)
  ["_soap_version"]=>
  int(1)
  ["sdl"]=>
  resource(4653) of type (Unknown)
  ["__default_headers"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(SoapHeader)#1640 (4) {
      ["namespace"]=>
      string(136) "/RoyalMailShipping/reference/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
      ["name"]=>
      string(8) "Security"
      ["data"]=>
      object(SoapVar)#1649 (2) {
        ["enc_type"]=>
        int(147)
        ["enc_value"]=>
        string(820) "

                user@domain.comAPI
                4d+PCTIxEWdlZA2Zr/OkvOXlTv4=
                MTAzMzg5Njc5NA==
                2016-12-13T10:20:46Z

        "
  }
  ["mustUnderstand"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

}
}

I'm not sure how to debug this as I'm not getting any errors, I have increased php memory_limit but that didn't helped either. I'm using PHP version 5.6.27

Comment: Few things, have you checked the error logs? Have you got errors turned on in php? Do you have the php openssl module installed and active? This last one has caused me no end of hell in the past

Comment: I have checked error logs and if I pass an empty parameters array in the __soapCall an error is logged to a file: `PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'integrationHeader' property` which indicates that wsdl and xsd is loaded. Adding the parameters array back in __soapCall just stops executing the script :(

Errors logging and openssl are enabled.

Comment: I know it sounds stupid. But have you spoken to Royal Mail? Could be a timeout issue their end? Also, aside from php memory limit, have you changed the timeout time from 30s? Checked you can actually ping / reach the endpoint normally?

Comment: Royal Mail can't see anything in their logs that I'm even reaching their end.
I can reach the endpoint normally by typing the url in the browser. I've increased timeout to 60s